# How to optimize static elements`s performance in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

In my scene. I painted a large map by plane and line. This map is static.

And then I need mount many moving cars in my scene.

But the performance is readly bad because the map.

**So do we have a solution to optimize static elements in threejs?**

I have tried set `matrixautoupdate` to false, but it still has bad performance.

Comment: Please include in your question: Example code showing the same behavior (so we can look for spots where we can help optimize your code) and describe anything else you have done to try to improve performance. I find it very hard to believe that a plane and some lines are causing performance issues, unless you have unoptimized meshes with hundreds of thousands of vertices.

Comment: @TheJim01 Actually, I am using 3000-5000 lines, and 1000-3000 plane to render a map.

Comment: As a first step, try combining them. Your thousands of lines can likely be represented as a single [`LineSegments`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/LineSegments). If you have individual textures for each plane, perhaps you could combine the textures and render a single subdivided plane? Reducing your scene from 4000-8000 objects down to two should give an immediate performance boost.

Comment: @TheJim01 I use BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries to combine my planes. It works!